# Number of mappers while doing distcp

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, distcp

How can I set the number of mappers to do distcp job? I know that we can set the max number of mappers by doing Hadoop `distcp -m`. But is it possible to set the number instead of the maximum number of mappers?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

**No**, It's not possible to set exact number of mappers for `distcp` up to now.

As you said, we can only specify **Maximum number of simultaneous copies** with `-m`. Hadoop hdfs handles simultaneous copiers to finish copy job in best possible way. so it might be the reason to not letting us to specify exact number.

[distcp - hadoop 2.7.2](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html#Map_sizing)